# How to enable Admins to see Plugins

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin

I am running a multisite network on the latest version of WP. I am the Super Admin.

I setup a user as "Administrator" on a site in the network. The Admin User cannot see the plugins menu.

I completely Network Deactivated all plugins and re-Activated them at the site level.

The Admin User still cannot see the plugins menu.

How can I grant Plugin access to a secondary/alternate Admin?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [Network Admin Settings screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen) (in my installation, it's at `example.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php`). Tucked away down near the bottom is this:

> ### Menu Settings
>
> Enable administration menus   [] Plugins

Checking that box should allow your users to see the **Plugins** menu in their sites' back end. (I don't think it'll allow them to install new plugins. I haven't tried it out yet, though, so test it before you put it into production.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this - it worked for my situation - `add_submenu_page( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/multisite-super-admin/includes/admin/settings.php', "Plugins", 'Plugins', 'administrator', '/plugins.php', '') ;`

The URL there is to a plugin I wrote. so you will want to add this to your own plugin. Very straight forward.

Learn more about it here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Comment: Correct solution is the one from Pat J.